# What are the first steps while restructuring a project?

Tags: process, organizational-structure, process-improvement, impediment

As a part of a course I am currently taking at university, we were given a report of an imaginary project that is currently going wrong and was put on hold.
While reading the report and analysing some interviews with some of the employees, we identified several problematic areas that are likely to have lead to the project fail:

- The project did not use a project management model at all
- Because of that, project goals and milestones were not defined sufficently and formally
- No unified way of documentation was provided, which made the current state of the project intransparent
- We thought that the organizational structure of the company making the project was not appropriate, because of too many departments being "on the same level in the tree" (see image below)

After identifiying these issues, we're wondering what a professional controlling company would request as the **next general steps to make to fix these problems**.

I'm not asking for a detailed list here, as this is our task, but I am thankful for any general hints, if there are some steps that are typically performed or generally considered as standard. 
Thanks for your expertise.

[image: Image of the company structure]

Comment: What's the priority here? The project is now on hold. Do you want to fix the issues with the project first, then work to improve the problematic areas (or at the same time)? Or do you want to fix the project by addressing the problematic areas first? What's the first priority here?

Comment: I would say the task is to address/restructure/solve the problematic areas first. When the necessary changes are done, then the project is going to be continued. Hope this answers your question, thank you.

Comment: From a project management perspective, terminated projects aren't automatically restructured and restarted. Organizational restructuring is also out of scope for a typical project management perspective; it's more of a business process concern. If it's decided that the project should be rebooted, I'd say you should recharter the project, which is not the same thing as restructuring your organization.

Answer (score 2):

When a project is stopped, that signals a rather significant intervention subsequent to a very unhealthy project. Notwithstanding the analysis that revealed several contributing problems, there are likely other problems that are unknown to you that still exist and may contribute to your next iteration of issues.

Since the project has stopped and you are no longer spending project funds, my approach would be to take advantage of this time and restart this project as if it is brand new, i.e., go through all the project start-up steps that you would do for a brand new project. This includes getting the project re-approved, re-chartered, building new sponsorship, and then conducting your next scoping and planning activities.

The con to this approach is that it might take a bit more time than just trying to cure the issues you uncovered, but the competing pro is that you have the opportunity to fix things you may not even know is broken. And you still have the opportunity to reuse existing project materials so that the new start-up won't be as onerous as a new project.

Comment: Thanks for this interesting perspective, I wouldn't have thought of that. 
So, when you propose restarting the project more or less from scratch, is there a standardized model / approach that you would recommend to follow while doing so? Are there models that also regulate the organizational structure of the departments involved in the project?